# VBA - Remove Brackets {} from GUID

Tags: string, vba, guid

Hi I just implemented the new fix for generating GUID codes after the microsoft update. I am very new with VBA, could you help me with removing the {} curly brackets generated with the GUID from the below code please.

```
 Private Type GUID_TYPE
            Data1 As Long
            Data2 As Integer
            Data3 As Integer
            Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As LongPtr
Public Function GetGUID()
            Dim guid As GUID_TYPE
            Dim strGuid As String
            Dim retValue As LongPtr
            Const guidLength As Long = 39 'registry GUID format with null terminator {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

            retValue = CoCreateGuid(guid)
            If retValue = 0 Then
                            strGuid = String$(guidLength, vbNullChar)
retValue = StringFromGUID2(guid, StrPtr(strGuid), guidLength)
                            If retValue = guidLength Then

GetGUID = strGuid
                            End If
            End If
```

End Function

Comment: For example : guid = '{abcd}'; then use "new_guid = Replace(Replace(guid, "{", ""), "}", "") "

Answer (score 0):

Edited this line.

GetGUID = Replace(Replace(strGuid, "{", ""), "}", "")

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Mid` to remove the first and last character.
You could also use an array of bytes to hold the guid and the result string.

To generate a GUID:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (pguid As Byte) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (rguid As Byte, lpsz As Byte, ByVal cchMax As Long) As Long


Public Function GenerateGUID() As String
  Dim pguid(0 To 15) As Byte, lpsz(0 To 77) As Byte

  CoCreateGuid pguid(0)
  StringFromGUID2 pguid(0), lpsz(0), 39
  GenerateGUID = Mid$(lpsz, 2, 36)
End Function
```